# E11000 duplicate key error even if inserted values for the unique field are different

Tags: mongodb

My MongoDB query:

```
collection.insertOne({word: 'lovely'})
```

Query not successful even if: **lovely # love**

```
WriteError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: English.keywords index: word_text dup key: { : "love", : 1.0 } :
WriteError({
    "index" : 0,
    "code" : 11000,
    "errmsg" : "E11000 duplicate key error collection: English.keywords index: word_text dup key: { : \"love\", : 1.0 }",
    "op" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5cbeb84d1442bb8732372b83"),
        "word" : "lovely"
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoDB applys stemming if a language is specified for a text index. This means reducing each word to its root form e.g. "lovely" to "love".

This could be causing your problem as "love" would be inserted as "love" and later if attempting to insert "lovely" this will also reduce to "love", causing a duplicate key error.

See the [Text Indexes documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/#supported-languages-and-stop-words):

> **text** index tokenizes and stems the terms in the indexed fields for the
>   index entries. **text** index stores one index entry for each unique
>   stemmed term in each indexed field for each document in the
>   collection. The index uses simple language-specific suffix stemming.

If you want to avoid this, you can specify a language of none:

> If you specify a language value of **"none"**, then the **text** index uses
>   simple tokenization with no list of stop words and no stemming.

I would also think about your index strategy. A unique text index wouldn't make sense for most use cases. If you are indexing individual words that you know are unique and you don't want to stem them, consider a regular index on the field.

Comment: Great! If you like, you can click on the check mark beside the answer to mark it as accepted, so that other users know this question is solved. It's not mandatory and you can also wait for another answer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: That's pity, i have not enough reputation to vote up your great answer. But i'll go back to vote it when I have enough condition

Comment: You don't need to vote it, just click on the grey check mark beside the answer. And you don't need any reputation to do that. But it's not a problem either way :)

Comment: oh, i did it :))